# GitPython - script error - already exists and is not an empty directory

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have a script that makes a clone of the repository I need. This script must be executed every day, i.e. reload data from the repository. There are no problems with cloning itself - the first launch downloads all the necessary files. But the next one knocks out this error.

```
stderr: 'fatal: destination path 'C:/Users/tred1/Desktop/WORK/Р°РЅР°Р»РёР·Р°С‚РѕСЂ/GHR_Y00011450/Data' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Those. I cannot clone a directory to a folder where it already exists. Which sounds pretty logical. I'm just learning how to work with git and sometimes I don't quite understand the commands.

Here is some of the code that does the cloning

```
class CloneProgress(RemoteProgress):
    def update(self, op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message=''):
        pbar = tqdm(total=max_count)
        pbar.update(cur_count)

def save (source, directory):
    Repo.clone_from(source, directory,  branch='master', progress=CloneProgress())
```

How can I update and add new files from this directory to bypass this error? Maybe there is some method?

Comment: You should learn Git first

Answer (score 4):

If you want to udpate an already cloned repo you do a pull

```
def save (source, directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        Repo.clone_from(source, directory,  branch='master', progress=CloneProgress())
    else:
        repo = Repo(directory)
        repo.remotes[0].pull()
```

Answer (score 0):

hm, I think it can help you
**Explanation**

This is pretty vague but I'll do what I can to help.

First, while it may seem daunting at first, I suggest you learn how to do things from the command line (called terminal on OSX). This is a great way to make sure you're putting things where you really want to.

You should definitely google 'unix commands' to learn more, but here are a few important commands to help in this situation:

ls - list all files and directories (folders) in current directory

cd  - change directory, or change the folder you're looking in

mkdir  - Makes a new directory (be careful, you will have to cd into the directory after you make it)

rm -r  - Removes a directory and everything inside it

git clone  - Clones the repository into the directory you are currently browsing.

**Answer**

So, on my computer, I would run the following commands to create a directory (folder) called projects within my documents folder and clone a repo there.

Open terminal
cd documents (Not case sensitive on mac)
mkdir projects
cd projects
git clone https://github.com/seanbecker15/wherecanifindit.git
cd wherecanifindit (if I want to go into the directory)
p.s. wherecanifindit is just the name of my git repository, not a command!

Comment: now I'm trying to implement this process through a "remote.pull"